# Counting Occurrences of one Column in Multiple Columns in a Different Table

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-workbench

I have two tables, let's call them Table1 and Table2. Table1 has a column c1. and Table2 has two columns called c2 and c3.

I would like to count the occurrences of c1 from Table1 in both columns of Table2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.c1, count(*) FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.c1 IN(SELECT c2 OR c3 FROM Table2)
GROUP BY NAME;
```

This apparently did not work for me, I am trying to practice different operations in SQL but I couldn't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

- Do not mix `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.  Since you are using an "aggregate function" (`COUNT(*)`), use `GROUP BY`.
- The list in the `GROUP BY` (`NAME`) should match the non-aggregate columns in the `SELECT` (`Table1.c1`)
- `OR` is a boolean operator, such as testing whether either of two things is true.  It cannot be used for collecting things.
- `UNION` (see below) can collect stuff from two tables (or 2 different columns in the same table, in your case).
- Try to avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )`; learn about `JOIN`.

The union:

```
(
    SELECT c2 FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c3 FROM Table2
)
```

effectively build a temporary table with one column, called `c2` (after the name(s) in the first `SELECT`).

Use `UNION DISTINCT` if you need to de-duplicate the results.

Now, Abdul, take these bits of knowledge and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to JOIN both tables. For `mysql` v8+ you can use CTE syntax:

```
WITH t1 AS 
( SELECT DISTINCT c1 
    FROM table1
) 
SELECT t1.c1
     , count(1) AS counter
  FROM t1
  JOIN table2 AS t2  ON t2.c2 = t1.c1
                     OR t2.c3 = t1.c1
 GROUP BY t1.c1
```